# jsp data to excel/CSV

Tags: jsp, flash

See the link below-
https://nseindia.com/ChartApp/install/charts/mainpage.jsp

This link basically plots Nifty index data...

When you hover mouse over any of those candles, then it displays the open,high,low,close,time and volume at that particular time. What i assume is that this data is downloaded somewhere in the computer.

I want this data for all times in a single CSV/XLS file  .... Is it possible?

I am a noob in coding hence need your help.

Tried google for help but no luck

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 0):

> *"When you hover mouse over any of those candles, then it displays the open,high,low,close,time and volume at that particular time. What i assume is that this data is downloaded somewhere in the computer."*
>
> *"I want this data for all times in a single CSV/XLS file .... Is it possible?*"

It might be possible for some outsider request to access same data. But it will take some hard work...

1) The chart is generated by a POST request for data from: [**GetHistoricalNew.jsp**](https://nseindia.com/ChartApp/install/charts/data/GetHistoricalNew.jsp).

2) The request is expected to include `lParams` so look for `var lParams = "";` in the page source code.

As you can see from the source code : 
`view-source:https://nseindia.com/ChartApp/install/charts/mainpage.jsp`

It builds up a request with these params via some function:

```
var lParams = getCurrentParams();
```

And the required `getCurrentParams()` function exists at: [**selector.jsp**](https://nseindia.com/ChartApp/install/charts/selector.jsp).

Somehow it makes a request to [**GetHistoricalNew.jsp**](https://nseindia.com/ChartApp/install/charts/data/GetHistoricalNew.jsp) with parameters like: 
 
`Instrument`, `Segment`, `CDExpiryMonth` and `CDDate1` ... etc.

An example request might look like:

```
https://nseindia.com/ChartApp/install/charts/data/GetHistoricalNew.jsp?Instrument=XXX&Segment=XXX&Series=XXX&CDExpiryMonth=XXX...etc...etc...
```

Replace `XXX` with actual param values. All you can do is read, and then read again, the source code to understand how these param values are decided. Then try to make a request structured like my example request shown above.

For example:

```
<option value="FUTSTK">FUTSTK</option>
<option value="FUTIDX">FUTIDX</option>
<option value="FUTIVX">FUTIVX</option>
```

Will let you know that `&Instrument=` has possible values of either : `FUTSTK`, or `FUTIDX` or `FUTIVX`.

Another example: in function `changeFilter`, things like...

```
if(pValue==SEGMENT_CM)...etc code to read...
```

Will let you know that `&Segment=` has possible values of:

- `&Segment=SEGMENT_CM`
- `&Segment=SEGMENT_FO`
- `&Segment=SEGMENT_CD`
- `&Segment=SEGMENT_INDEX`

The last line at bottom `return lParams;` will give the type of params you need in your own request (to get the same information that the website app receives).

```
function getCurrentParams()
{
    lFrm=document.form1;
    var lParams="";
    var instru = lFrm.Instrument.value;
    lParams+="Instrument="+lFrm.Instrument.value;

    //added by swapnil for FUTIVX instruement type on 20 Jun 2014
    if(lFrm.Segment.value==SEGMENT_INDEX || (lFrm.Segment.value == SEGMENT_FO && (lFrm.Instrument.value == "FUTIVX" || lFrm.Instrument.value == "FUTIDX")))
    { lParams+="&CDSymbol="+escape(lFrm.CDSymbol_Index.value); }
    else 
    { lParams+="&CDSymbol="+escape(lFrm.CDSymbol.value); }

    lParams+="&Segment="+lFrm.Segment.value;
    lParams+="&Series="+lFrm.Series.value;
    lParams+="&CDExpiryMonth="+lFrm.CDExpiryMonth.value;

    //Added by swapnil for FUTIVX instruement type on 23 Jun 2014
    if(lFrm.Instrument.value == "FUTIVX")
    { lParams+="&VIXExpiryMonth="+lFrm.VIXExpiryMonth.value; }
    else
    { lParams+="&FOExpiryMonth="+lFrm.FOExpiryMonth.value; }

    lParams+="&IRFExpiryMonth="+lFrm.IRFExpiryMonth.value;
    lParams+="&CDIntraExpiryMonth="+lFrm.CDIntraExpiryMonth.value;

    if(lFrm.Instrument.value == "FUTIVX")
    {
        //Added by swapnil for FUTIVX instruement type on 20 Jun 2014
        lParams+="&VIXIntraExpiryMonth="+lFrm.VIXIntraExpiryMonth.value;
    }
    else 
    { lParams+="&FOIntraExpiryMonth="+lFrm.FOIntraExpiryMonth.value; }  

    lParams+="&IRFIntraExpiryMonth="+lFrm.IRFIntraExpiryMonth.value;
    lParams+="&CDDate1="+lFrm.date_FromDate.value;
    lParams+="&CDDate2="+lFrm.date_ToDate.value;
    lParams+="&PeriodType="+lFrm.PeriodType.value;
    lParams+="&Periodicity="+lFrm.Periodicity.value;
    setCurrentParamHash(lParams);

    return lParams;

}
```